# Is it possible to avoid copying from another section in stack initialisation in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, x86

for example

```
void f()
{
   wchar_t s[]=L"aaaaaaaaa";
}
```

is compiled into something like

```
.section .rdata
LC0:.ascii "a\0a\0a\0a\0a\0a\0\0"
.section .text
movl LC0,%eax
movl %eax,0x888(%esp)
...
```

Is it possible to avoid the dependence on another section? Such as

`movl $0x00610061,0x888(%esp);movl $0x00610061,0x88c(%esp);...`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enable optimization so bad code is to be expected.  [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point)

**`gcc -O3 -m32` does use mov-immediate for this.**

(Use `volatile` so the array doesn't optimize away, of course.  Or pass a pointer to it to a non-inline function).

```
# gcc9.3 -m32 -O3
f():
        sub     esp, 48
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp+8], 97
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp+12], 97
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp+16], 97
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp+20], 97
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp+24], 97
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp+28], 97
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp+32], 97
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp+36], 97
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp+40], 97
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp+44], 0
        add     esp, 48
        ret
```

64-bit code copies in 16-byte chunks.  (Unfortunately not using a broadcast-load even if SSE3 or AVX are available). https://godbolt.org/z/AsdbWU

That's pretty clearly worth it, although `movabs` with a 64-bit immediate and four qword stores + 1 dword would have been not terrible.

```
# gcc9.3 -O3 -march=skylake
# with the default tuning / arch options, same code but without "v"
f():
        vmovdqa xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]      # should have used vpbroadcastd
        vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp-56], xmm0         # it chooses two 16-byte stores
        vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp-40], xmm0         # maybe to avoid a vzeroupper or alignment isn't known
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-24], 97           # scalar mov-immediate for the last one
        ret
.LC0:
        .quad   416611827809
        .quad   416611827809
```

Comment: Seems like OP's `wchar_t` is 2 bytes, which would make the code more similar to [this](https://godbolt.org/z/igvGjh) (but yeah, basically same story).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: oh right, on Windows `wchar_t` is 2 bytes.  But yeah, same story, fortunately the answer doesn't hinge on that fact.